# Getting a transparent background with terminator -- so I can see the X11 root window behind, *not* other windows

Tags: linux, transparency, openbox, terminator, compositing

I use Terminator 1.90-1 and Openbox 3.6.1 on a Debian system. Recently a new version of Terminator stopped supporting transparency, and I was advised to install a compositing program like xcompmgr or compiz since Openbox does no t handle compositing itself. I did, and it worked, except that the result is not the same.

- In a previous version of Terminator, the background le tme see *the X11 root window*. If I put another application behind Terminator, I wouldn't see it.
- Using a compositing manager, Terminator becomes truly transparent, and I can see applications behind it (firefox, Emacs, and others) -- which is quite annoying and distracting to me.

Is there a way to get a transparent background on Terminator so I could see the X11 root window behind it (and not other windows)?

Thnak you!

PS: it looks like other terminal emulators like `lilyterm`, `xfce4-terminal` behave similarly. If there is ano tabbed terminal taht would allow me to set the background as I mentioned, I'd be glad to know (but it would probably have to not depend on vte, since vte itsef stopped supporting transparency, as far as I understand)

Comment: When you say the root window, do you mean your desktop background?

Comment: Yes, the X11 background, which I set with Eterm